# How to prevent default event actions all over the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is to find a way to call `preventDefault` automatically on events of a chosen type throughout the whole application. It seems very redundant to me to write `e.preventDefault()` in every `onSubmit` handler. So, is there any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just build your own `Form` component?

Comment: Uhm, that's just a great idea. Thanks, and shame on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName(body);
el.addEventListener("click", modifyEvent, false); 

function modifyEvent(){
    event.preventDetault();
}
```

Comment: Well, it would get it done as an outer hack. But I'd rather use some inner React.js feature, if there is one. Thank you for suggestion.